# infinite-dimensional inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra, infinite-product

I've been asked to get an example of an infinite-dimensional inner product space, so I wrote this

> [image]

As an example is there anything wrong with what I wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example: infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces are inner product spaces and they have infinite dimension. $l^2$ is a well known example of infinite dimensional Hilbert space (and actually, every infinite dimensional *separable* Hilbert space is isometrically isomorphic to $l^2$).

Your example, including the definition of the usual inner product on $l^2$, is correct. There is only a typo: you should write $\overline{\omega}_i$, not only in the "compact" sum notation, but also when you explicitely write the first terms of the series. Moreover, do not stop to $z_n \overline{\omega}_n$: write '$+...$'. Of course, recall that this series is evaluated w.r.t. the norm induced by the inner product.

Comment: thank you, you helped me a lot